# Content Resolver - How to sum up a column value for all rows using query

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am working on a project using Content Provider for DB.
I am able to fetch all rows using the query mentioned below.
My problem is I want to sum up a column for all rows fetched.

I am querying as :

```
String query = WorkTable.ENTRY_TIME + " = ?"
String projection = "new String[]{WorkoutLogTable.STEPS}";
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                .query(
                        LogProvider.WORK_LOG,
                        projection,
                        query,
                        new String[]{dateString},
                        null
                );
```

I want the sum of `WorkoutLogTable.STEPS`. Projection needs `string[]` as parameter, so how can I sum up the STEPS value?

**Edit**

I used a projection:

```
String projection = new String[]{"sum(WorkoutLogTable.STEPS}) as total"};
```

But it's also not working.

**Solution:**

I was doing a mistake by making the whole part as string.
So I have resolved so:

```
String projection = new String[]{"sum(steps) as total"}; // steps is my column name and I was fetching it by WorkoutLogTable.STEPS which was wrong
```

Or another solution can be using Dynamic string (from `cricket_007` answer)

Comment: If you can get all the rows, couldn't you simply sum the column from Java?

Comment: That I can do iterating cursor, but its good if I get direct sum from query. Because there can be multiple rows and I don't want to iterate over too many rows.

Comment: The `SUM` function would also iterate all the rows of the database, though... Anyways, you could try to make your projection `"sum(" + WorkoutLogTable.STEPS + ") as total"`. Having Java syntax inside of a SQL statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: Its default method Not exactly what I will do if I iterate using cursor.

Answer (score 2):

> Projection needs `string[]` as parameter,

Right, so why is your `projection` variable a `String`? This statement won't even compile.

```
String projection = "new String[]{"sum(WorkoutLogTable.STEPS}) as total"};
```

Maybe you meant this?

```
String[] projection = new String[] { "sum(" + WorkoutLogTable.STEPS + ") as total" };
```

---

You need to use an actual `String[]` object, not a `String` that has the content of `"String[] { ... }"`

```
String selection = WorkTable.ENTRY_TIME + " = ?"
String[] projection = new String[] { "sum(" + WorkoutLogTable.STEPS + ")" };
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { dateString };

Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(
                LogProvider.WORK_LOG, 
                projection, 
                selection, 
                null, null);
```

Comment: Its String[] but there is only one field. Array can have single value also.

Comment: Yes, arrays can have single values, but your usage of the [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) method isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a content provider from another app?  If you are writing the content provider, I would recommend that you add another URL specifically for the summary query and do your sum function in the query inside the content provider.  Then just use the alternate URL when you go through the content resolver.

Comment: If you have a question about what I am proposing, post your content provider code and I will update my answer.

Comment: No Its not from another app. I just want to sum up the column for all rows. I can able to fetch the rows.